# How do I include `applicationIdSuffix` in some generated resource value?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Imagine this setup:

```
android  {
   buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
   }
   productFlavors {
       foo {
           applicationId defaultConfig.applicationId + '.foo'
       }
   }
```

}

How can I set up a dynamic string value such as

```
resValue "string", "package_name", applicationId
```

so that it includes the `applicationIdSuffix` for debug builds?

If I add this to `defaultConfig`, its my defaultConfig's applicationId that is set. If I add this to the flavor configuration, it is missing the `applicationIdSuffix` (this is `null` at this level).

Any hints?

Comment: *If I add this to*, what's `this`?

Comment: @Blackbelt The `resValue` stanza.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cool part about applicationIdSuffix is that you can use it in flavors as well as in build types. Check this out:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dev.bmax.suffixtext"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        prod {
            applicationIdSuffix '.prod'
        }
        mock {
            applicationIdSuffix '.mock'
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I build my 'prodDebug' variant the final application ID is 'dev.bmax.suffixtext.prod.debug', which is what you want if I understand your question correctly.

**EDIT**

1. You can access the variant's name in a Gradle task like this:

   ```
   applicationVariants.all { variant ->
       // Use 'variant.name'
   }
   ```
2. Gradle Android Plugin version 0.14.3 added support of the variant specific BuildConfigField/resValue:

   ```
   applicationVariants.all { variant ->
       variant.resValue "string", "name", "value"
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok, I did not knew that `applicationIdSuffix` is also available on flavor level, but this is not actually my problem. I want the _resolved_ application ID to be written to the generated strings.xml so that I can reference it e.g. in a preference screen XML configuration.

Comment: I assume, you generate the strings in a Gradle task. Try using ${variant.name} instead of 'applicationId'.

Comment: `> Could not find property 'variant' on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=dev, dimension=backend, minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null, applicationId=my.app.id, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}.`

Comment: It should be accessible if you wrap your task in: android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
   ....
}

Comment: Ok, I thought something like this :) But can I work with `resValue` at this point at all?

Comment: Perfect! `variant.resValue` indeed worked! And I get the `applicationId` from the variant's properties, like so: `variant.resValue "string", "package_name", "${variant.properties.applicationId}"`